# Find specific combinations of files of commits in git

Tags: git, docker-compose, tags, find, commit

I have the following situation that i would like to solve. I am currently focussing on using git for this, but it might not be the right path.

I have a file docker-compose.yml, let's call this file A
and a file, docker-compose.override.yml, let's call this file B
(in the future we also have additional files, but since that is basically a repeat of the situation, we ignore this expansion for now)

Different Versions of A and B are represented using v1.0 etc, IE: Av1.0 and Bv2.1

We start with Av1.0 anv Bv1.0
We then add Av1.1 (and therefor keep Bv1.0)
then we add Bv1.1
etc. From a historic sense you get to see something like this:

```
Av1.0  Bv1.0
Av1.1  Bv1.0
Av1.1  Bv1.1
Av2.0  Bv1.1
Av3.0  Bv1.1
Av3.0  Bv3.0
```

(remember, the files are named A and B, only the contents is different)

How can i find a specific version set from the repo in such a way that:

- able to find a specific version of A
- able to find all versions of B related to this version A

I thought about using tags and specific commit strings, but i would also like users to commit new versions of A or B without having to adhere to very strict text inputs (tags or commits) because a typo is easilly made.
The other solution would be to completely automate the adding to the repo, but i don't know were to begin. So any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't even see Git having to be part of this.  The files which version numbers all appear to exist at every commit.  You might want to use something like `grep` based on a certain pattern.

Comment: the content of the files change, not the name itself. Therefor we would need multiple directories. That would be an option, but i prefer to use a git-style manner, if there is one.

Comment: At this moment we are thinking about using tags that are automatically placed, so no user errors, using a git hook. And then we can choose the tags to get to the right combination.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well after much searching and reading, I found a way to get it done.

Using a combination of branching and tagging we can achieve the desired results.

How?

- every major versions gets it own branch
- every minor version is committed under the major-version-branch
- every version is tagged using a versioning system that matches the releases

so the latest version of a major release can be found under the branches
Any other needed version can be found by using the tags that are given to each commit.

Important: tagging is done by using git commit hooks. Because tagging should not be done by a human because of typos or other issues. And tagging can only be done after a succesfull commit.

It will in the end look something like this:

```
Av1.0  Bv1.0  <- branch 1.0 tag 1.0-0
Av1.1  Bv1.0  <- branch 1.1 tag 1.1-0
Av1.1  Bv1.1  <-            tag 1.1-1
Av2.0  Bv1.1  <- branch 2.0 tag 2.0-0 (it is the first version in this branch, so it is a 0)
Av3.0  Bv1.1  <- branch 3.0 tag 3.0-0
Av3.0  Bv3.0  <-            tag 3.0-1 (it is the 2nd version of B in this branch so it gets a 1)
```